# JQuery is working fine with integer but not with string in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Jquery is working perfectly fine with integer var but got error for string. My code is as below.

```
@section Scripts {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $.getJSON('/Service/ListServiceType', function (result) {
                    var ddl = $('#ServiceType');
                    var type =  @Model.Type;
                    ddl.empty();
                    $(result).each(function () {
                        $(document.createElement('option'))
                            .attr('value', this.Type)
                            .text(this.Type)
                            .appendTo(ddl);
                    });
                    $("#ServiceType").find("option").each(function () {
                        alert($(this).val())
                        if ($(this).val() == type) {

                            $(this).prop("selected", "selected");
                        }
                    });
                });

                $.getJSON('/Category/ListCategory', function (result) {
                    var ddl = $('#CategoryType');
                    var id = @Model.CategoryId;
                    ddl.empty();
                    $(result).each(function () {
                        $(document.createElement('option'))
                            .attr('value', this.Id)
                            .text(this.Name)
                            .appendTo(ddl);
                    });
                    $("#CategoryType").find("option").each(function () {

                        if ($(this).val() == id) {

                            $(this).prop("selected", "selected");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    }
```

Lower part(/Category/ListCategory)works perfectly fine but not the upper one. As I am new in JQuery and Javascript so a little help would be appreciable.

Comment: What is the problem area? Narrow it down and post only relevant portion

Comment: What is `Model.Type`?

Comment: The problem is at line var type =  @Model.Type; Here Type is string.

Comment: What value do you see when you put a breakpoint to inspect this @Model.Type?

Comment: Take a look at the method that returns the @Model to make sure Type is what you are expecting.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: use `var type = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Type))`

Comment: The error was Uncaught ReferenceError: ROOT is not defined however you solution worked. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String type should be in quotes.

Change this

```
var type =  @Model.Type;
```

to

```
var type =  '@Model.Type';
```